# How to match string in URL using Nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, rewrite

I have sett up reverse proxy with Nginx reverse proxy is just working fine as expected.
I have another scenario where i need to redirect URL based on matching string using proxy_pass.

ie : http://xx.xx.xx.xx:81/crawlers/587dbbf8e4b0b5cea2c4a49e/execute?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.massimodutti.com%2Fes%2Fhombre%2Faccesorios%2Fbolsas-c1748214p7722308.html%3Fkeyword%3DBANDOLERA%2520PEQUE%25C3%2591A%2520PIEL%2520BURTON%26colorId%3D700&token=5892cf1cf056fa9ac307a39c&

This is the rest call i want if URL contains massimodutti.de so it should be route to german servers using proxy_pass

currently i am blank and searching for solution any help will be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

You should use the nginx map feature to map query arguments into `proxy_pass` destinations. It works like this:

In the nginx configuration `http` level, you add a map like this:

```
map $arg_url $proxyserver {
    default default.server;
    "~\.de" german.server;
}
```

where you replace `default.server` with the domain name for default server and `german.server` with the domain name for your german server.

Then, you use `proxy_pass http://$proxyserver;` in your `server` block for the reverse proxy destination definition.

Answer (score -2):

I have achieved this by adding these lines in my nginx reverse proxy configurations $args is case insensitive searching method it will search ".de" in requested URL and proxy the request.

if ( $args ~ ".de" ) {
proxy_pass http://104.xx.xx.xx:80;
}

if ( $args ~ ".ca" ) {
proxy_pass http://104.xx.xx.xx:80;
}

Comment: This is the wrong way to do it. Look at the answer above, and read this article https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Comment: i have tried again didn't working for me either i can't share full logs here
Here is my configuration .....

server {
        listen 80;

location ~* massimodutti.de {
  proxy_pass xx.xx.xx.xx:80
}

location / {

#if ( $args ~ ".de" ) {
#proxy_pass http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xx;
#}

Comment: A better match can be achieved by using `$arg_url` instead of `$args`. Then nginx will match the `url` query argument instead of the complete argument string. The most recommended way is described in my answer.